# Ruby file from rake task problem - does not create file

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a rake task that loads file directories from a configuration file.

For each directory I want to run a ruby script. The filepath is correct, since when I run it independently it works. But called from the rake file it doesn't work.

The ruby script file content is the following:

```rb
File.open("some_file_name.txt", "w") { |file| file.puts "I wrote this with ruby!"}
puts "TAADAAA"
puts "#{__dir__}/some_file_name.txt"
```

When I run it from the rake task the output is:

> /home/csrhub/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/ruby /home/csrhub/v2-live-csr-api-rb/bin/restart
>
> TAADAAA
>
> /home/csrhub/v2-live-csr-api-rb/bin/some_file_name.txt

But no file created in the directory.
Then I copy-paste the first part of the output `/home/csrhub/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/ruby /home/csrhub/v2-live-csr-api-rb/bin/restart` and run it from the shell, I get the output file. But from the rake task the file does not appear.

Comment: `File.open("some_file_name.txt", "w") {.....}` will create a file **in the current directory** (assuming there's no other crucial code you've omitted.) Which is not necessarily the same thing as the folder of the execution script. In other words, unless you're already inside the `bin/` folder, it's not going to create a file inside `bin/`.

Comment: `__dir__` is the folder from which a method is called. This is not necessarily the same as folder that the script is being executed from.

Comment: tl;dr: Did your rake task create a file at the root of the project, rather than insider `bin/`?

Comment: @TomLord, Probably it has created the file somewhere int FSystem but I cant find it

Comment: @TomLord, So how to give the file a context?

Comment: @TomLord

 This one works `File.open("/home/csrhub/v2-live-csr-api-rb/bin/some_file_name.txt", "w") { |file| file.puts "I wrote this with ruby!"}`I can see the file created by the task. So I beleive it has always created a file but somewhere else.
`

Comment: Offf. This solved the problem `File.open("#{__dir__}/some_file_name.txt", "w") { |file| file.puts "I wrote this with ruby!"}
`

Comment: Your original code was perfectly fine. If you run the rake task in `/home/csrhub/v2-live-csr-api-rb`, then it will create a file: `/home/csrhub/v2-live-csr-api-rb/some_file_name.txt`. Without the `/bin` folder. Did you check to see if the file was actually created at the root of the project?